# R: Populate a new column in a dataframe based on matching one or several possible strings

Tags: regex, r, dataframe, pattern-matching, match

Hypothetical dataframe:

```
strings      new column
mesh         1
foo          0
bar          0
tack         1
suture       1
```

I would like the new column to contain "1" if df$strings contains the strings "mesh", "tack", or "sutur". Otherwise it should display zero in the same row. I tried the following:

```
df$new_column <- ifelse(grepl("mesh" | "tack" | "sutur",
  df$strings, ignore.case = T), "1", "0")
```

but got this error:

```
Error in "mesh" | "tack" : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use a single string in `grep`:

```
df$new_column <- ifelse(grepl("mesh|tack|sutur", df$strings, ignore.case = T),
                       "1", "0")
```

will work, but the following will be faster:

```
df$new_column <- +(grepl("mesh|tack|sutur", df$strings, ignore.case = T))
```

This will return a 0 and 1 integer vector

Answer (score 3):

We can also use `%in%`

```
df$new_column <-  as.integer(df$strings %in% c("mesh", "tack", "sutur"))
```